# Cannot understand what is going on with rstrip('\n')

Tags: python, stack, strip

I am reading a book called *Data Structure And Algorithm In Python*. Unfortunately, I am stuck now.

It is about rewrite lines in a file in reverse order using stack.

You can ignore `ArrayStack` class, since it is just there to build a stack.
Please see the reverse_file function.

```
''' Thanks Martineau for editing this to transform bunch of lines to code!'''
class Empty(Exception):
    ''' Error attempting to access an element from an empty container.
    '''
    pass


class ArrayStack:
''' LIFO Stack implementation using a Python list as underlying storage.
'''
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Create an empty stack.
        '''
        self._data = []  # nonpublic list instance

    def __len__(self):
        ''' Return the number of elements in the stack.
        '''
        return len(self._data)

    def is_empty(self):
        ''' Return True if the stack is empty.
        '''
        return len(self._data) == 0

    def push(self, e):
        ''' Add element e to the top of the stack.
        '''
        self._data.append(e)  # new item stored at end of list

    def top(self):
        ''' Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
        '''
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Stack is empty.')
        return self._data[-1]  # the last item in the list

    def pop(self):
        ''' Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e, LIFO)

        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
        '''
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Stack is empty.')
        return self._data.pop()


def reverse_file(filename):
    ''' Overwrite given file with its contents line-by-line reversed. '''
    S = ArrayStack()
    original = open(filename)
    for line in original:
        S.push(line.rstrip('\n'))
    original.close()  # we will re-insert newlines when writing.

    # now we overwrite with contents in LIFO order.
    output = open(filename, 'w')
    while not S.is_empty():
        output.write(S.pop() + '\n')
    output.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reverse_file('6.3.text')
```

The book says we have to use `.rstrip('\n')` method, because otherwise the last line of the original is followed by (without newline) the second last line with a special case in which a file does not have a blank line at the final - as you know, pep8 always catch you with "no newline at end of file".

But why this happens?

Other lines are fine, but why does only the last line have that problem?

If `'\n'` will be deleted by `.rstrip('\n')`, why does it matter whether or not it has a new line at the final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

newline characters separate lines. By definition, all lines except the last one must have newline characters... because that's what makes them lines. The final line may or may not have a newline character. You know its the end of the line simply by the fact you reached the end of the file.

Think of a simpler algorithm. You read the lines into a list, reverse and write the items of the list. Because of reverse, the last line is now the first line. If it didn't have a newline, when you write the first and second items become the first line.

Its fixed by stripping newlines and manually adding them at the end. `rstrip` checks whether there is a newline at the end and removes it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I, now, perfectly got this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might over-complicate things. Effectively you remove every `'\n'` with the `line.rstrip('\n')` upon reading. The `S.pop() + '\n'` simply inserts this for every line upon writing. Otherwise you will end up with a single long line.

Some files do not have a `'\n'` at the end. This entire process is proposed to insert a line break between the last and the second to last line when writing them in reverse, otherwise these two would merge.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. After I realized that I over-complicated this, my head has been finally working.